# What does the .substring(3) function do?

Tags: apex, string, substring

See I'm getting this field from an integration with wooki, and the field should go to Salesforce in currency format. I get it with the following value: `BRL 20.000,00 (Twenty thousand reais)`I need to treat this value, removing the letters, removing the "." and replacing the "," with "." The final result should be a decimal `20000.00`
So far I'm:

```
//With this line I get the result I want
acc.Capital_Social__c= Decimal.valueOf((String.valueOf(results.get('capital_social')).replaceAll('[^0-9,]', '')).replace(',', '.'));
```

The problem is that before I implemented this solution, this was the code used:

```
acc.Capital_Social__c = Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(results.get('capital_social')).substring(3).remove('.').replace(',', '.'));
```

You will notice that I stopped using the function

```
.substring(3)

acc.Capital_Social__c= Decimal.valueOf((String.valueOf(results.get('capital_social')).replaceAll('[^0-9,.]', '')).substring(3).remove('. ').replace(',', '.'));
```

Because when I put it the result generated is: `0.00`

I don't understand why I get this result 0.00
I don't understand what this ".substring(3)" function was doing in the old code, on google I didn't enter an explanation about this function. I'm afraid that she will be missed at some point.
I would like to know if anyone knows this function, if they understand its purpose, if it is really needed, and why it is returning 0.00

Comment: The `substring` method doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [String class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substring)

> #### substring(startIndex)
>
> Returns a new String that begins with the character at the specified zero-based startIndex and extends to the end of the String.

So given that `String.valueOf(results.get('capital_social'))` evaluates to `BRL 20.000,00 (Twenty thousand reais)`...

following that with `substring(3)` was previously how you were removing the "BRL" (but not the space between that and the numeric portion) from the beginning of your string.

`substring(3)` cuts out the first 3 characters (the returned string starts with character 4 (i.e. index 3) of the original string)

```
 B  R  L     2  0  .  0  0  0  ,   0   0  ...
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12]...
[discard][             keep              ]
```

When you changed the code to use `.replaceAll('[^0-9,.]', '')` though, that was taking care of removing the "BRL " (with the space) as well as the "(Twenty thousand reais)", leaving you with `20,000.00`

By keeping the `substring(3)`, you were now discarding part of your desired data

```
 2  0  .  0  0  0  ,  0  0
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
[discard][     keep       ]
```

Now your string is `000,00`, and you remove "." (which doesn't exist in your string at this point) and replace(',', '.').

So the final step in that statement is effectively `Decimal.valueOf('000.00')`.

Leading zeros are removed, except for the first digit, leaving you with your observed value of `0.00`.

By removing the `substring(3)`, the rest of your steps were working on the value `20.000,00`. With no data discarded, the rest of your processing steps ended up as `Decimal.valueOf('20000.00');`

Comment: As an aside, one of the fundamental skills in programming is being able to build a "mental model" of what your code is doing. Understanding what each part of a statement does (and knowing the order in which things are evaluated) makes it a lot easier to see potential issues.

Comment: Thank you, i undestand now, thank you @DerekF